# How to disable checkstyle JavaDoc validation for constructors?

Tags: java, javadoc, checkstyle

How to disable checkstyle JavaDoc validation for constructors?

I see that http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_javadoc.html#JavadocMethod states clearly that it "Checks the Javadoc of a method or constructor", however I need to exclude constructors and leave only methods.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In order to ignore constructors, remove the `CTOR_DEF` token from the `tokens` property, for example:

```xml
<module name="JavadocMethod">
  <property name="tokens" value="METHOD_DEF,ANNOTATION_FIELD_DEF"/>
</module>
```

This is achieved by setting `tokens` to all the other allowed tokens except `CTOR_DEF`. Unfortunately, for this to work, you need to know which tokens to set, and this list varies by Checkstyle version and is not always accurately reflected in the [docs](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_javadoc.html#JavadocMethod). This above example should provide a reasonable setting.

Comment: The default values for JavadocMethod include `CTOR_DEF`, `METHOD_DEF` and `ANNOTATION_FIELD_DEF`.

Of these 3, `CTOR_DEF` is responsible for Constructors - so you should remove only that and put the other two viz. `METHOD_DEF` and `ANNOTATION_FIELD_DEF` instead of just `METHOD_DEF`.

Comment: @MuchMore You are right, answer updated. Thanks! In my defense, the additional token was not on the list when I wrote the original answer. ;-)

Comment: @ThomasJensen For this to work I had to use "target" as the name of the property instead of "tokens" as you mentioned it.

Comment: @Rlarroque Interesting - I can't find a property called `target` on this check, even in the oldest or newest versions of Checkstyle. Sure that there is no mixup of some kind?

Answer (score 2):

Ignore javadocs *only* on constructors with a custom class...

```
<module name="org.example.MyJavadocMethodCheck">
...
</module>
```

which looks like:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class MyJavadocMethodCheck extends com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.checks.javadoc.JavadocMethodCheck {

    @Override
    public int[] getAcceptableTokens() {
        return Arrays.stream(super.getAcceptableTokens())
            .filter(t -> t != TokenTypes.CTOR_DEF) // Don't enforce javadoc comments on constructors
            .toArray();
    }
}
```

I'm sure I found this on stackoverflow but can't find the exact link anymore.

Comment: This is basically correct, but way too complicated. The check has a `tokens` property to configure this behavior. No need for a custom check.

Comment: The amount of code with a custom class is indeed more. The only benefit here is that I don't need to know "all the other allowed" values when using "tokens" (METHOD_DEF,ANNOTATION_FIELD_DEF ...) but rather exclude just the one(s) I'm interested in (CTOR_DEF).

Answer (score 1):

Since Checkstyle version `3.21`, to ignore Javadocs for constructors you need to use `MissingJavadocMethod` module, with the property `tokens` set to `METHOD_DEF , ANNOTATION_FIELD_DEF , COMPACT_CTOR_DEF`:

```
<module name="MissingJavadocMethod">
  <property name="allowMissingPropertyJavadoc" value="true"/>
  <property name="tokens" value="METHOD_DEF , ANNOTATION_FIELD_DEF , COMPACT_CTOR_DEF "/>
</module>
```

For more information about the `MissingJavadocMethod` module: https://checkstyle.sourceforge.io/config_javadoc.html

Comment: It's weird that you answered this 2014 when Checkstyle 3.x was the newest version. Now, 2023, Checkstyle 10.x is the newest version and https://checkstyle.org/checks/javadoc/missingjavadocmethod.html#MissingJavadocMethod states that the `MissingJavadocMethod` module exists since 8.21. Anyway, it helped me.

Comment: The question is dated from 2015, I answered the question on 14 of March this year :)

Comment: Oh damn, you're right. My bad, hehe. So you're not from the future after all.